# What is the difference between a class teacher and a form teacher?

Tags: word-request, word-difference, transatlantic-differences

I can't get which one, class teacher or form teacher or homeroom teacher, in the UK and the US, is what we call "professeur principal" in French secondary schools, meaning one of the teachers of a class of 25 to 30 students who not only teach them their own subject, but also are in charge of their pupils as far as their overall school life and academic performance are concerned, checking out that they are doing well or helping them overcome the difficulties they might be going through.

Comment: Is this question specifically about British English?

Comment: The Wikipedia article for *professeur principal* is linked to *homeroom*, which is not a type of teacher but a concept related to the organization of the school day, used primarily in North America but apparently also in the antipodes. Please [edit] your post to explain what a *professeur principal* is or does, and what locale you are seeking a term for—educational terminology varies very widely from system to system, region to region.

Answer (score 6):

Well for me this is how it goes.

Before and after school, in the Uk, in most schools, you have form where you take a register and do different stuff.

That is what I would call a *form tutor*.

Whereas someone who teaches lessons is a *class teacher*

In the USA this is called a *homeroom* and the person who is in charge is the *home room teacher*

Comment: This is what I expected, but I am not familiar with the UK school system. As @choster's comment mentions, this would be called *homeroom* in the USA, and the person in charge would be the *homeroom teacher*. Perhaps you could include the USA variants in your answer?

Comment: With UK schools I recall hearing the expression "first form".  Is there a "second form"?

Comment: @Andrew yes it relates to your year in the school, I believe

Comment: I think form teacher and class teacher are the same. They look after a class or form or cohort: attendance, consolidating grades and producing report cards. A subject teacher on the other hand, is tasked with teaching a specific subject or course to that class.